# MacVim GUI doesn't use XDG vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim

I just finished setting vim to use XDG variables (mostly taken from [here](https://tlvince.com/vim-respect-xdg)), where:

`XDG_CONFIG_HOME`: ~/.config

`XDG_CACHE_HOME`: ~/.cache

When I launch MacVim from the terminal using `mvim`, everything specified in my `vimrc` is read.

However, when I open a file from the file manager (GUI), the `vimrc` is not read.

How do I ensure that GUI MacVim behaves like `mvim`?

Below in the Vim configuration in my `.zshrc`:

```
# Vim
export VIMINIT='source $MYVIMRC'
export MYVIMRC=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/vimrc
export VIMDOTDIR=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim
```

---

More info:- ZSH is the default shell

There is a `.zshenv` file in `$HOME` with:

```
# ZSH
export ZDOTDIR="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME/.config/zsh}"

# XDG compliant home directory
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export XDG_CACHE_HOME="$HOME/.cache"
export XDG_DATA_HOME="$HOME/.local/share"
```

The `.zshrc` is located in `$HOME/.config/zsh`

Answer (score 1):

Your environment variables are visible to `mvim` because they are set for the context in which it is executed.

Your environment variables are invisible to MacVim.app because they are not set for the context in which it is executed.

The most likely explanation is that zsh is not your system's login shell, so the commands in your `~/.zshrc` are not executed when you log in, which makes your environment variables non-existing.

If that is the case and you want your environment variables to be global, you will have to either:

- export them in the proper rc file of your login shell,
- or tell your system to use zsh as your login shell.

Comment: I think she'll variables won't work in a GUI app like MacVim.app. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57402) for ideas how to set env variables for specific apps.

Comment: This is one way to do it but environment variables work perfectly in GUI apps, specifically MacVim, if they are set in the login shell, @filbranden

Comment: See also [`:h macvim-login-shell`](https://macvim.org/docs/gui_mac.txt.html#macvim-login-shell)